# A problem about an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve
 $$4\frac{d^{4}y}{dt^{4}}＝\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}$$？

Thanks for your help

Comment: May be, $v=y''$ could be a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a double integration, we get

$$4y'''=y'+C$$ and

$$4y''=y+Cx+D$$ or

$$y-4y''=Cx+D.$$

with no RHS, the solution is

$$y_h=Ae^\frac{x}{2}+Be^\frac{-x}{2}$$

a particular solution is given by

$$y_p=Cx+D.$$

thus, the general solution is

$$y_g=y_h+y_p$$

$A,B,C,D$ are real constant.